Proof of the principle of explosion
The Wikipedia page uses the following proof for the statement:

P     (Premise)
¬P    (Premise)
P ∨ Q (Disjunction Introduction)
Q     (Disjunction Syllogism)

There are two issues, to me:

this proof specifically deals with contradictions, not any false proposition;
I could prove the same thing using the definition of P -> Q as not P or Q which would make the implication true whenever not P, not only when P is a contradiction


In the proof, P is presumably meant to be the false statement. Since the point of the proof is to show what you can prove given a false premise, the proof also has to include the premise that P is false. That's what the ¬P premise is. In other words, the contradiction arises from including both a false premise and a premise saying that the false premise is false.

I am not sure what your problem is. As the Wikipedia page correctly says, the principle of explosion is a rule of classical logic under which any proposition can be proved from a contradiction. You cannot prove any proposition from a contingent falsehood.

See Difference between implication/conditional and logical entailment?

@Bumble my problem is: if $P\to Q$ is equivalent to $\neg P\lor Q$, then the implication is true whenever $P$ is false in general, not specifically a contradiction.

"the implication is true whenever $P$ is false in general, not specifically a contradiction" That's right. This is how implication works in classical logic. An implication is true in classical logic if its premise is false or its conclusion is true.

@AdamPřenosil okay. Then why does the proof on Wikipedia assume that the premise is specifically a contradiction, and not any false proposition?

Because you cannot derive the conclusion Q from the premise ~P, but you can derive the conclusion Q from the premises P and ~P.

The material conditional P → Q is indeed logically equivalent to ¬P ∨ Q. From that it follows that P → Q is deducible from ¬P. But it doesn't follow that Q is deducible from ¬P. To deduce some arbitrary Q we need both P and ¬P, i.e. we need a contradiction.

@AdamPřenosil DAMN I JUST GOT IT. I have no idea why it was so hard for me to grasp, thank you so much.

There are different yet equivalent axiomatizations of propositional logic, and one that I’ve used actually has the principle of explosion as an axiom:

A Contradictory Statement Entails X, for all well-formed formulae X (i.e., for all expressible propositions in some system of propositional logic).

In that case, we wouldn’t have to prove it, since it’s already given.
In the Wikipedia example above, they use the disjunction introduction axiom that if P is true, then P or Q is true for any Q. And in that proof above, they start with the assumption that in some situation, both P and not P are true. This allows us to derive Q because of the axiom of ‘disjunction syllogism’, which is that if P or Q and not P, then Q.
That proof shows that for arbitrary P, if it ever holds that both P and not P are true, then for arbitrary Q, you can prove Q. That is, as long as you have a contradiction, you can prove anything, like so:

P and not P are true.
If P is true, then P or Q is true.
If P or Q is true and not P is true, then Q is true.

Or:

P and not P are true.
If not P is true, then not P or Q is true.
If not P or Q is true and P is true, then Q is true.

The main trick in each proof is to associate either P, or not P, with arbitrary Q, which is what the axiom of disjunction introduction allows us to do. Once we have done that, just consider what the other statement about P (not P, or P), then implies.
A more intuitive way to think about the principle of explosion comes from thinking about material implication (the -> symbol). The way it is defined, the formula P -> Q is true, whenever P is false. I think of P -> Q as saying “Whenever P is true, so is Q”. This means that we “don’t care” about the situation when P is not true: whether Q is or is not true, we just evaluate P -> Q to true, since it did not violate the condition.
Look at the truth table to confirm this:



P
Q
P → Q




T
T
T


T
F
F


F
T
T


F
F
T



If you can come to understand that, given the way P -> Q is defined in propositional logic, whenever P is false, P -> Q is true, the principle of explosion follows because a contradiction is a statement that is always false!
For arbitrary P -> Q, we do not yet know if P is true or false. But if P is a contradictory statement, like “It is raining and it is not raining”, this will always be false. Since it is always false, and since an implication is always true if the premise is false, then every formulable implication will evaluate to true, given a contradiction as its premise.

That was exactly my issue: a contradiction is always a false proposition, but not all false propositions are contradictions. Using the first proof, the principle only applies to contradictions, but looking at the truth table it would apply to any false statement.

@Elvis Assuming any false proposition to be true automatically gives you a contradiction. If P is a false proposition but we assume it to be true, than what does that mean for not-P?

If there's a false statement among the premises the conclusion can be either true or false.
A false premise and a true conclusion

All men are mortal
All dogs are men (false premise)
Ergo,
All dogs are mortal

A false premise and a false conclusion

All cats are dogs (false premise)
All dogs are wolves
Ergo,
All cats are wolves

A false proposition is kinda like a contradiction in this regard ... anything follows.
Here are other (more extreme) examples:
All premises false and false conclusion

All planes are colors
All colors are stars
Ergo,
All planes are stars

All premises false but true conclusion

All lions are humans
All humans are carnivores
Ergo,
All lions are carnivores

Logical valid argument forms "work" only with true premises, if truth (of the conclusion) is your goal. Inject false premises and you can end up with "anything" (true/false conclusion).
Also, notice how we can prove literally all propositions with (a) false premise(s) [that is/are not contradiction(s)].
